# jquery all value is not empty then show submit button else not show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one question about selectbox. I have to create this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/uHGtg)**

In this demo you can see there is a blue button. What i am trying? I am trying if all values is not 0 then `show` button. If all value is 0 then button `hide`.

What should i do for it ?

```
$(function(){
  $("select").change(function(){
            $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=="Satılık"){
                    $(".met").show();
                    $(".de").hide();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="Kiralık"){
                    $(".met").show();
                    $(".de").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="GünlükKiralık"){
                    $(".de").hide();
                    $(".met").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="Satılıki"){
                    $(".de").hide();
                    $(".met").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="Kiralıki"){
                    $(".de").show();
                    $(".met").show();
                 }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="Devren"){
                    $(".de").hide();
                    $(".met").show();
                 }

            });
        }).change();
});
```

Comment: You forgot to save demo URL. Your link is pointing to the new workspace.

Comment: @VisioN I am really sorry. I updated my DEMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are trying to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/fekktthj/1/ ?

I added a few lines that check the value of the last select as follows:

```
$(function(){
  $("select").change(function(){
    $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="Satılık"){
            $(".met").show();
            $(".de").hide();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="Kiralık"){
            $(".met").show();
            $(".de").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="GünlükKiralık"){
            $(".de").hide();
            $(".met").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="Satılıki"){
            $(".de").hide();
            $(".met").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="Kiralıki"){
            $(".de").show();
            $(".met").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="Devren"){
            $(".de").hide();
            $(".met").show();
        }

    });
    if(($('select[name=isinma_tipi]').val() ==null) || $('select[name=isinma_tipi]').val() ==''){
      $('#submitBtn').hide();
    }else{
      $('#submitBtn').show();
    }
}).change();
```

I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

set the css on the button to "display: none;" or a js on load like "$('#submitBtn').hide();"

Jquery

```
$('#model').click(function(){
   if($(this).val() !== "")
     {
       $('#submitBtn').show();
     }
  else{
    $('#submitBtn').hide();
  }
});
```